# SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix from read access on the file

Tags: php, linux, sendmail, selinux, rocky-os

Why I'm getting the "SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix from read access on the file ..." every time I send an email in PHP?

No Idea why sendmail needs to read a PHP file.

According to the log, the source and target context are different. But it's not clear if this is the problem or not.

Log shows:

```
SELinux is preventing /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix from read access on the file /var/www/html/send-email.php.

*****  Plugin catchall (100. confidence) suggests   **************************

If you believe that sendmail.postfix should be allowed read access on the send-email.php file by default.
Then you should report this as a bug.
You can generate a local policy module to allow this access.
Do
allow this access for now by executing:
# ausearch -c 'sendmail' --raw | audit2allow -M my-sendmail
# semodule -X 300 -i my-sendmail.pp


Additional Information:
Source Context                system_u:system_r:system_mail_t:s0
Target Context                unconfined_u:object_r:httpd_sys_content_t:s0
Target Objects                /var/www/html/send-email.php [ file ]
Source                        sendmail
Source Path                   /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
Port                          <Unknown>
Host                          xxxxxxxxxx-prod
Source RPM Packages           postfix-3.5.9-19.el9.x86_64
Target RPM Packages
SELinux Policy RPM            selinux-policy-targeted-34.1.43-1.el9_1.2.noarch
Local Policy RPM              selinux-policy-targeted-34.1.43-1.el9_1.2.noarch
Selinux Enabled               True
Policy Type                   targeted
Enforcing Mode                Enforcing
Host Name                     xxxxxxxxxx-prod
Platform                      Linux xxxxxxxxxx-prod
                              PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Wed Mar 1 22:02:24 UTC 2023 x86_64
                              x86_64
Alert Count                   3283
First Seen                    2023-03-30 18:03:38 CEST
Last Seen                     2024-02-29 12:16:58 CET
Local ID                      43f6879e-354b-4593-b3a4-90adc111f26c
```

I'm using Rocky Linux, 9.1.

Can you help me to understand what's happening?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Unix and its utilities. [unix.se] or [su] would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: Check your Postfix configuration. It's probably using that script for something.

Comment: Yes, I already did it and read about sendmail and postfix. But I don't understand why sendmail needs to read a PHP file when I'm using the mail() function. I don't want to add a new rule in SELinux until I understand why this is happening.

Comment: You can configure postfix to run arbitrary scripts when processing mail, e.g. for spam detection, customized mail routing, etc.